# Multiple images/buttons staying relative to their position on a zoomable image

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've made a map with UIScrolView, I want to place other small images or buttons onto the map and have them be in a relative position on the map when you zoom in and be able to click on them whenever. So when zoomed out, a button on country A, will still be on Country A when zoomed in, and disappear out of the screen when you scroll out of the countries view whilst zoomed in. How could I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i can understand, you want to place custom views on your own custom map. And you need to keep the same sizes for views, but they should move when you scroll or zoom imageView.
You have to place views to scrollView's superview and recalculate positions when you zoom or scroll:

CustomMapViewController.h:

```
@interface CustomMapViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
{
    UIScrollView *_scrollView;
    UIImageView *_mapImageView;

    NSArray *_customViews;
}
```

CustomMapViewController.m:

```
#import "CustomMapViewController.h"

enum {
    kAddContactButton = 1,
    kInfoDarkButton,
    kInfoLightButton,
    kLogoImage,
};

@implementation CustomMapViewController

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_scrollView release]; _scrollView = nil;
    [_mapImageView release]; _mapImageView = nil;
    [_customViews release]; _customViews = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void) loadView
{
    [super loadView];

    UIImageView *mapImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"map.png"]];

    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.2;
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2.0;

    [scrollView addSubview:mapImageView];
    scrollView.contentSize = mapImageView.frame.size;

    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

    _scrollView = scrollView;
    _mapImageView = mapImageView;

    // Add custom views
    UIButton *btn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
    btn1.tag = kAddContactButton;
    [self.view addSubview:btn1];

    UIButton *btn2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark];
    btn2.tag = kInfoDarkButton;
    [self.view addSubview:btn2];

    UIButton *btn3 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
    btn3.tag = kInfoLightButton;
    [self.view addSubview:btn3];

    UIImageView *image = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]] autorelease];
    image.tag = kLogoImage;
    [self.view addSubview:image];

    _customViews = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:btn1, btn2, btn3, image, nil];

    [self _zoomToFit];
}

- (void) _zoomToFit
{
    UIScrollView *scrollView = _scrollView;
    CGFloat contentWidth = scrollView.contentSize.width;
    CGFloat contentHeigth = scrollView.contentSize.height;
    CGFloat viewWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat viewHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height;

    CGFloat width = viewWidth / contentWidth;
    CGFloat heigth = viewHeight / contentHeigth;

    CGFloat scale = MIN(width, heigth); // to fit
    // CGFloat scale = MAX(width, heigth); // to fill

    // May be should add something like this
    if ( scale < _scrollView.minimumZoomScale ) {
        _scrollView.minimumZoomScale = scale;
    } else if ( scale > _scrollView.maximumZoomScale ) {
        _scrollView.maximumZoomScale = scale;
    }

    _scrollView.zoomScale = scale;
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#pragma mark - Positions

- (void) _updatePositionForViews:(NSArray *)views
{
    CGFloat scale = _scrollView.zoomScale;
    CGPoint contentOffset = _scrollView.contentOffset;
    for ( UIView *view in views ) {
        CGPoint basePosition = [self _basePositionForView:view];
        [self _updatePositionForView:view scale:scale basePosition:basePosition offset:contentOffset];
    }
}

- (CGPoint) _basePositionForView:(UIView *)view
{
    switch (view.tag) {
        case kAddContactButton:
            return CGPointMake(50.0, 50.0);

        case kInfoDarkButton:
            return CGPointMake(250.0, 250.0);

        case kInfoLightButton:
            return CGPointMake(450.0, 250.0);

        case kLogoImage:
            return CGPointMake(650.0, 450.0);

        default:
            return CGPointZero;
    }
}


- (void) _updatePositionForView:(UIView *)view scale:(CGFloat)scale basePosition:(CGPoint)basePosition offset:(CGPoint)offset;
{
    CGPoint position;
    position.x = (basePosition.x * scale) - offset.x;
    position.y = (basePosition.y * scale) - offset.y;

    CGRect frame = view.frame;
    frame.origin = position;
    view.frame = frame;
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate

- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self _updatePositionForViews:_customViews];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self _updatePositionForViews:_customViews];
}

- (UIView *) viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
{
    return _mapImageView;
}

@end
```

Comment: Wow it works perfectly, Thank you! But I'm having some problems with my starting map size. I want it to start completely zoomed out to fill the screen (aspect ratio is correct), I managed to do it with my previous program but I can't seem to get it to work with yours.

Comment: I add _zoomToFit method and call it from loadView.
Also you needn't call _updatePositionForViews from loadView, because when you change zoomScale in _zoomToFit, delegate method will call it for you.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry to ask so many questions, but I've just realised that some of the custom buttons do need to be resized. I'm guessing that it should be very similar to _updatePositionForView: but I have no idea about how to go about it, math isn't my strongest point.

Comment: I fixed this line: **CGFloat viewHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height**
and if you need scale to fill, then use MAX instead of MIN: **CGFloat scale = MAX(width, height);**
If you need resize these buttons when zooming, then just add these buttons directly to imageView, and they will zoom automatically, don't add it to _customView array

Comment: Just imported this into my main program and I get this error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer position contains NaN: [nan nan]'

Comment: Also, using [_mapImageView addSubview:btn1]; fixes the resizing of buttons, but the problem with zoom position is back again.