# add object to image view, how to keep object location when zoom image

Tags: android, object, zooming

I have an image, my job is how to zoom it to see detail with object. After a lot of searchs, I decided to use [Touch Image VIew class](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/ortiz/touch/TouchImageView.java)

But my problem is when zooming this image, the object i add to this image by called ((ViewGroup)image.getparent).addview(object) have problem.

That is this object can not change it position when I zoomed, you can see my picture here:

[image]

You can see the icon Android i added into picture.

Here is the picture when i zoomed it

[image]

I can not find the way how to display this object icon to exactly new position when zoom image. Please help me

EDIT: If you use google map app. My job is write app like that but used image with object instead of using google map with marker

I found a solution in IOS, but it's seem not working in android:[Multiple images/buttons staying relative to their position on a zoomable image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13444619/multiple-images-buttons-staying-relative-to-their-position-on-a-zoomable-image)

Comment: you can set imageurl in webview and add zoom in and zoom out button in webview and you can easly load your image url in webview

Comment: Hello, thanks for your helping, but i have to write offline app. So i can not use you suggest....

Comment: Hi due find any solution.. I am too looking for it.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43652348/user-location-is-not-setting-on-exact-position-on-floorimage

Comment: hi. i found solution: https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view/ can do everything i need :)